# interbase.interclient.UnlicensedComponentException with the latest interclient.jar IB (v7.5.80)

Tags: java, jdbc, interbase

We're trying to open a connection using Java 8 spring application to a legacy interbase database on a remote server stored on some file.gdb.
The interclient.jar (interbase jdbc driver) was obtained through their SDK\lib folder extracted from embarcadero interbase developer edition.

our application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.InterbaseDialect
spring.datasource.username=sysdba
spring.datasource.password=masterkey
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=interbase.interclient.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:interbase://192.168.1.100:3050/d:/test.gdb
```

We're getting this exception from the remote host (tried also locally with 'localhost'):

```
2015-01-20 18:45:32.628 ERROR 8880 --- [           main] o.h.h.spi.PersistentTableBulkIdStrategy  : Unable obtain JDBC Connection

interbase.interclient.UnlicensedComponentException: [interclient] Unlicensed component: This version of InterClient refuses communication with InterBase version WI-V7.5.1.80/tcp (Merav28-Srv)/P14.
See API reference for exception interbase.interclient.UnlicensedComponentException
    at interbase.interclient.Connection.remote_ATTACH_DATABASE(Unknown Source)
    at interbase.interclient.Connection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at interbase.interclient.Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at interbase.interclient.Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:701)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:635)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:486)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:144)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:116)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:103)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl$2.obtainConnection(SessionFactoryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.PersistentTableBulkIdStrategy.exportTableDefinitions(PersistentTableBulkIdStrategy.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.hql.spi.PersistentTableBulkIdStrategy.prepare(PersistentTableBulkIdStrategy.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1857)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:843)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:842)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:120)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:648)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:909)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:898)
    at com.supersmart.prices.mazon.data.jpa.SampleDataJpaApplication.main(SampleDataJpaApplication.java:30)
```

We will appreciate any help solving this issue to be able to open a connection programatically to this interbase instance.

Comment: Did you contact the Embarcadero support? If there is a "API reference for exception interbase.interclient.UnlicensedComponentException" maybe it is helpful.

Answer (score 3):

So eventually we ended up using jaybird legacy 1.5 driver to connect the interbase 7.5.80 database server and it is working fine for our needs.

If it helps anyone you can grab the legacy jars here:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/firebird-jca-jdbc-driver/