# Where to get InterClient 2.01 source code?

Tags: open-source, legacy, interbase

We have a legacy facility that uses InterBase 5.6.

The latest Java client library that could access it is the InterClient 2.01.

There're an [InterClient 2.01](http://sourceforge.net/projects/firebird/files/OldFiles/) binaries on SourceForge (look for `interclient_201_*` files), and there are some clues in the readme and around the web that the source for this version was released somehow (check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterBase#Open_source) and [maillists](https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/mailman/firebird-devel/?viewmonth=200109&viewday=12) - I've encountered the same wording [in multiple places](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/borland.public.interbase.opensource/Qhtc1t7nkCc) where people're discussing the fact that the 2.01 sources *were published* but were erroneously tagged as 2.00).

I've looked over the web and haven't found these sources anywhere. Seems that they have been lost.

Could anybody give me a direction - where to look for these sources? There are [some weird errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25365952/noclassdeffounderror-sun-io-bytetocharconverter-with-interbase-jdbc-driver) in them so I'd like to maybe somehow fix them and publish the fixed version in Maven, so people could use them more easily and world becomes a little better place for live.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found them. They are here: http://firebird.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/firebird/interclient/20/dev/

(Note that they can be downloaded only from CVS and not from git.)

I've published the extracted source with history here: https://github.com/ForNeVeR/interclient

Comment: Just as a matter of interest, why don't you upgrade to an Open Source alternative to Interbase 5.6 - i.e. Firebird 2.5? It's available for both 32 and 64 bit. I'm just confused why this isn't an option and you're having to revise code that's 15 years old?

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is out of my jurisdiction. There's a big third-party system and its authors are extremely unwilling to ever make any changes. I've already reported to my manager that this piece of software will create pain in ass for us, but I don't think it will be removed or rewritten in the coming years.