# Migrating to JRE 1.8 - NEED Workaround for sun/io/ByteToCharConverter deprecated in JRE1.8

Tags: java, java-8

We will be migrating to JRE1.8 soon
we use db2jcc.jar and db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar to connect to DB2 which internally uses sun/io/ByteToCharConverter which is deprecated in JRE 1.7 and 
is removed in JRE 1.8. We need a solution for this issue. Please help.

Thanks
Lakshmi

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/25365952/2670892

Comment: Thanks Greg, Please can you help with the actual jars link , I see they are using jaybird jars , Is that a standard solution ? Please advice

Comment: I just found the duplicate, I don't know any more than it says there. Have you asked IBM if they have a more up to date jar?

Comment: No Greg will check with IBM please let the question be open if some one else has a better solution to the problem It will help Thanks